# Trying to draw on a JPanel without success

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm trying to learn drawing with swing. I'm trying to create a circle and position it on a specific position in a JPanel. This is what I've come up with but it does not show any figure:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Circles extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Circles(){
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
}
}
```

This is the class that starts the program.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StartCircles extends JFrame{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Circles circle;
public StartCircles(){
    Container c = getContentPane();
    circle = new Circles();
    c.setBackground(Color.white);
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(300, 300);
    c.add(circle);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    StartCircles c1 = new StartCircles();
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I position the figure where I want?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  To turn those two codes into one SSCCE would probably only require demoting the `public` panel class to default, and pasting it into the end of the `StartCircles` class.

Comment: I compiled and run the code and it works,it shows a rectangle.

Comment: Don't forget to @Override paintComponent, I remember seeing that cause an issue before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Fixed]

Try this SSCCE - noting the comments in the source.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StartCircles extends JFrame{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Circles circle;
public StartCircles(){
    Container c = getContentPane();
    circle = new Circles();
    c.setBackground(Color.white);
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    //setSize(300, 300);
    c.add(circle);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack(); // size the GUI to the components within it
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    StartCircles c1 = new StartCircles();
}
}

class Circles extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Circles(){
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    //super.paintComponents(g);  // WRONG METHOD!
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
}
}
```

Comment: I still see a square. OP needs circle. Maybe curve the edges a little bit ? :-D

Comment: Swing GUIs should also be created and updated on the EDT.  Left as an exercise for the user.

Comment: @LittleChild  If you look at the question carefully, and my answer, you'll realize the main issue was not the shape.

Comment: I noticed that but why not finish off the answer in one shot ? :-D

Comment: Thanks for the help. But how do I position the rectangle where I want on in the container/component?

Comment: @LittleChild  Maybe I should.  But then, maybe I should have also corrected the problem of not creating the GUI on the EDT, refactored it to **not** extend `JFrame`, reworked it to draw into a `BufferedImage` displayed in a `JLabel`..  We have to make decisions as to how much to change the code to make a working version.  My decision in this case, was to stop there.

Comment: *"how do I position the rectangle where I want"*  Umm.. change the first two numbers passed to `drawRect(..)`?  Do you mean the programmer moving it at compile time, or the user moving it at run-time?

Answer (score 3):

Your code running perfectly, but you are drawing Rectangle here.
so if you want to draw circle, you have to use

one of below methods

```
g.fillOval(10, 10, 50, 50);

g.drawOval(10, 10, 50, 50);
```

Answer (score 2):

`g.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50);` is sure to get you a rectangle. You need to look at the documentation for how to draw a circle.

You need to draw it using `drawOval()`. It takes 4 parameters:

> x - the x coordinate of the upper left corner of the oval to be drawn.
>       y - the y coordinate of the upper left corner of the oval to be drawn.
>       width - the width of the oval to be drawn.
>       height - the height of the oval to be drawn.

So, replace your `drawRect()` with `drawOval()`